# Blazor-Server side authentication with Cookie

Tags: cookies, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to implement on a Blazor-Server side application a simple login against LDAP server and use cookie to store user claims. I have the MainLayout set to Authorized, if the user is not authenticated it will be re-direct to Login page. I have already tested the LDAP connection and it works properly, the problem is no matter what I do the cookie doesn't get created in the browser. When I run the POST command I see the HttpStatusCode.OK but the cookie it's not created and the browser re-direct again to login page of course.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? My code:

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
      services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

**AuthenticationController.cs**

```
    [ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("authentication/login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody]UserCredentials credentials)
    {
        string path = "LDAP://serveraddress.xxx";
        try
        {
            using DirectoryEntry entry = new(path, credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
            using DirectorySearcher searcher = new(entry);
            searcher.Filter = $"(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(samaccountname={credentials.Username}))";
            var result = searcher.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                List<Claim> claims = new();                 
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, credentials.Username));

                //Get Groups
                ResultPropertyCollection fields = result.Properties;
                foreach (var group in result.Properties["memberof"])
                {
                    var distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName(group.ToString());
                    var commonNameData = new AsnEncodedData("CN", distinguishedName.RawData);
                    var commonName = commonNameData.Format(false);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commonName))
                    {
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, commonName));
                    }
                }
                //Get Emails
                foreach (var email in result.Properties["mail"])
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email.ToString()));
                }

                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new()
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound("User Not Found!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return NotFound("Login credentials is incorrect!");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("authentication/logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Login.razor**

```
@page "/login"
@page "/login/{ErrorMessage}"
@layout CenteredBlockLayout
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<MudPaper Elevation="25" Class="pa-8" Width="100%" MaxWidth="500px">
    <MudItem><img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" style="width:400px; height:50px;" /></MudItem>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h4" GutterBottom="true">Sign In</MudText>
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="@Username" T="string" Label="Username"/>
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="@Password" T="string" Label="Password"/>
    <MudButton OnClick="(() => PerformLoginAsync())">Sign In</MudButton>
</MudPaper>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
{
    <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Error">@ErrorMessage</MudAlert>
}
```

**Login.razor.cs**

```
public partial class Login
    {   
        public string Username { get; set; }    
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        HttpClient Client { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        private NavigationManager NavMan { get; set; }
  
        private async Task PerformLoginAsync()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            {
                UserCredentials cred = new UserCredentials
                {
                    Username = Username,
                    Password = Password
                };

                var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cred);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(serialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using var result = await Client.PostAsync($"NavMan.BaseUri}authentication/login", stringContent);
                if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {                       
                    NavMan.NavigateTo("/", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorMessage = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to append the cookie to the response. I haven't tested this with your code but it should work something like this:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my_cookie", claimsString, new CookieOptions()
{
    Domain = "mydomain.com",
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
    Secure = true,
    Path = "/",
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
}
```

(These cookie options are just an example, of course. Tailor them to your specific needs.)

Keep in mind that you'll need to convert your claims to a string so that you can store it as the value in a cookie. In our case we store claims in a JWT, so that's what gets stored in the cookie. Here's how I do it:

```
public string CreateJWT(HttpContext httpContext, User user)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Config.AccessExpMins),
        Issuer = Config.Issuer,
        Audience = Config.Audience,
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(Key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
    };

    var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(descriptor);
    var accessToken = handler.WriteToken(token);

    httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my_cookie", accessToken, new CookieOptions()
    {
        Domain = Config.CookieDomain,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
        Secure = true,
        Path = "/",
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Config.AccessExpMins)
    });

    return accessToken;
}
```

As for parsing the JWT, I'm sure there are a number of ways to go about it. The one that worked for me was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404612/parse-jwt-token-to-get-the-payload-content-only-without-external-library-in-c-sh).

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you very much for helping!

I wanted to ask, do I need to append the cookie in the controller code between the SignInAsync() and Ok()? 
Or do I need to do it in the Login page after the post request?

Do you eventually have an example of storing/retrieving claims with JWT?

Comment: Happy to help! My suggestion would be to do it between the SignInAsync() and the Ok(). I've updated my answer to include my own example of creating a JWT, as well as a reference to a method for parsing the claims from one.

Comment: Oooh I see..so the way how JWT work is that the user type user/pwd in login screen, info are send to controller and if data are correct a token is generated with claims and returned to the login page. Then I need to parse the token, get all the claims and add them to the Blazor Identity service to tell the app that the user is authenticated and has X amount of claims. :)

Comment: Yep, you've pretty much got it. For added security you can even verify the token signature on the front end, provided you're using asymmetric key signing. All in how you want to implement it. Either way though I expect that should give you what you need.